# What is the difference between `rep-benchmark.sh`, `cli-benchmark.sh` and `benchmark.sh` in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently learning the `benchmark` tool in Apache IoTDB, but I am a little confused. I want to ask what is the difference between the function of `rep-benchmark.sh`, `cli-benchmark.sh` and `benchmark.sh`? What scenarios can I use these tools separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, `rep-benchmark.sh` means to compare results with other tests, and execute can multiple tests in one startup. `benchmark.sh` starts a single execution task and can dynamically view the running result information. The `cli-benchmark.sh` script can configure the path of IoTDB, and can automatically start IoTDB through this script, then perform read and write operations.